# Not getting the value for Logon user

Tags: asp-classic

I was trying to see the log on user with

```
<% 
Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") 
%>
```

I am not getting any output.Do I need to set some system settings for this ?I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your page accessed with 'anonymous' or are you authenticating? Authentication-related variables are not populated if you are using anonymous access. (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306359)

Comment: I made anonymous access disabled,started displaying the Logon user.